# Receive changing data into another controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, segue, swift5

I have a ViewController with a variable which value is changing every second ( from a sensor ).

I made another ViewController let's call it SensorViewController with a Label on the screen in which I want to display the value from the main ViewController.

If I use `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` the value is send but only one time ( it doesn't refresh/update every second ).

What can I do to change the value from SensorViewController every time the value from ViewController is changing?

Example:

```
// ViewController example code:
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
distanta1 = String(byteArray[0]) // variable which is changing every second
@IBAction func distantaSenzori(_ sender: UIButton) { //button which send me to SensorViewController
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSenzori", sender: self)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { // this one is sending value only when I press the button from above ( I have to exit from SensorViewController and enter again to see updated value )
    if segue.identifier == "goToSenzori"{
        let destinatieVC = segue.destination as! SensorViewViewController
        destinatieVC.distance1 = distanta1 } }
}

// SensorViewController code:
class SensorViewViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var distanta1: UILabel!
var distance1: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    distanta1.text = distance2 }
}
```

Thank you very much, guys! You are awesome!

For Frankenstein:

In class SensorViewViewController my code looks like that:

```
        var distance1: String?
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        distanta1.text = distance1
        print("Distance 1 is \(distance1)")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

It's called only once and the value is nil. What should I modify at the code here so the value to be refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an observer and keep reference to the destination view controller to keep passing in the new value that has been changed to the destination view controller. Here's how:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var distanta1 = String(byteArray[0]) {
        didSet {
            destinatieVC?.distance1 = distanta1
        }
    }
    //...
    var destinatieVC: SensorViewViewController?
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToSenzori" {
            destinatieVC = segue.destination as? SensorViewViewController
        }
    }
}
```

In SensorViewViewController:

```
var distance1: String? {
    didSet {
        print(distance1 ?? "")
    }
}
```

Better approach: Set the `destinatieVC?.distanta1.text = distanta1` directly if you're not doing anything else in the `didSet` block avoid the `distance1` property entirely.

Comment: My destinatieVC is nil in didSet, any idea why? 

Thank you very much for answering at my question!

Comment: It gets initialized once prepareforsegue is called.

Comment: I edited the original post with a question for you, can you please answer to that?

Thank you again for helping me, I'm a beginner at swift programming language.

Comment: Should I place like a while I'm in SensorView distanta1.text = distance1 ?

Comment: It's simple just add an observer just like the one in I've shown in view controller. Check the update I've just made.

Comment: Ok, so works very fine to print distance, from both ViewControllers , but when I'm trying to display it as a text in label, I'm getting a weird purple warning/error which says: "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only", I tried to solve it from google but without success.

Comment: Since the passing data part is working now you should close this post, upvote and mark the right answer. Don't ask follow up questions in comments open a new post for that. The above mentioned issue could be fixed if you googled a bit more, if you're still not able to solve add a new post.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot for all your help!
You saved me! Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome. Do more research and you'll do great. Also, upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner solution is to create a shared manager for handling the sensor. After that, you can notify your objects about the changing value. Of course in your case your "sensor" is something bluetooth but what I wrote is only a template basically, you can fill in your necessary methods and objects, delegates, so on.

```
class SensorManager {
    
    static let shared: SensorManager = SensorManager()
    
    private var sensor: Sensor
    
    private init() {
        sensor = Sensor()
    }
    
    //MARK: - Public methods
    
    func startTheSensor() {
        //This is what you call to start your sensor
    }
    
    func getSensorData() -> YourData {
        //This is from where your objects can read the sensor data
    }
    
    //MARK: - Private methods -
    
    private func didSensorUpdatedValue() {
        //This is called whenever your sensor updates
        
        .
        .
        .
        
        let newSensorValue = "yourValue"
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init("SensorDataChanged"), object: nil)
    }
    
}
```

In your viewcontroller:

```
deinit() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    weak var this = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(this, selector: #selector(didSensorValueChanged), name: .init("SensorDataChanged"), object: nil)
}


@objc func didSensorValueChanged() {
    SensorManager.shared.getSensorData()
}
```